# Nested virtualisation for VMs on Google Compute engine

Tags: linux, windows, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, virtualization

I need the image to be originally Ubuntu Linux but within it have a virtual machine of Windows running that is accessible to the internet

How can I accomplish this?
Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nested virtualization is available only for Haswell processors so before getting started make sure the instance's processor architecture checks out.

You will need to enable the nested virtualization first through either the API or the gcloud command.

You can follow along Google's documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances